# The proof about the countability of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let A be the set of all functions $f: N→N $ such that U=$\{i∈N∣f(i)≠1\}$ is finite. Is the set A finite, countably infinite, or uncountable?

My answer is that this A is a countably infinite set.

Because the set $U$ is finite, suppose $U=\{x_0,...,x_n\}$

Then for $x_0 \in U$ the functions in A can be $f_1,f_2,...$ with the property that:

$f_1(x_0)=2; f_2(x_0)=3,...$. First, these functions are different, and these functions are countably infinite since there is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and the subscript of the functions. Take the union of these functions to be $J_0$

Similarly, for $x_1\in U$. The functions in A can be $g_1,g_2,...$ with the property that:

$g_1(x_0)=2; g_2(x_0)=3;...$. In this collection of functions,it's possible to have $g_i=f_j$ but it doesn't matter, because this collection of functions is still contable. Take the union of these functions to be $J_1$

Similarly for $x_2,...,x_n$.

As result, take the union of $J_0,..., J_n=\bigcup_{0\leq i\leq n} J_{i}=A$. This is a finite union of countable sets and at least one $J_0$ is countably infinite. Thus, A is countably infinite.

Is this correct proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit ambiguously phrased. How I read it is that $f\in A$ if and only if $U_f:=\{i\in\mathbb N: f(i)\neq 1\}$ is finite. Your argument would then be incorrect, as each $U_f$ can have a different finite cardinality. In this case $A$ is still countable though. Indeed, for $f,g\in A$, we know that $f\neq g$ if and only if $U_f\neq U_g$, because $f(n)=g(n)=1$ for all $n\notin U_f\cup U_g$. We are thus asking how many different sets $U_f$'s there are, which is equivalent to asking for the cardinality of the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$. This is well known to be countable.